Using R to generate lifespan plots
I have a dataset that records the lifespan and generation time of individual cell that I would like to plot as below:
Example_RLS_plot
Reference:
https://doi.org/10.1186/s12951-022-01379-9
Here is my example dataset:
|   Cell   | Generation | Doubling_time |
| -------- | ---------- |-------------- |
|    1     |      1     |       40      |
|    1     |      2     |       70      |
|    1     |      3     |       80      |
|    1     |      4     |      100      |
|    1     |      5     |      100      |
|    1     |      6     |       80      |
|    1     |      7     |       90      |
|    1     |      8     |       70      |
|    1     |      9     |      190      |
|    2     |      1     |       50      |
|    2     |      2     |       90      |
|    2     |      3     |      100      |
|    2     |      4     |       90      |
|    2     |      5     |       80      |
|    2     |      6     |      160      |
|    2     |      7     |      250      |
|    2     |      8     |      170      |
|    2     |      9     |      170      |
|    3     |      1     |       60      |
|    3     |      2     |      100      |
|    3     |      3     |      100      |
|    3     |      4     |      150      |
|    3     |      5     |      100      |
|    3     |      6     |      130      |
|    3     |      7     |      120      |
|    3     |      8     |      450      |

I'm super newbie in R and my current statistic software (Prism) cannot tackle this type of the plots. I appreciate any lead for packages/sources to help me generate similar plots. Thank you so much!!
I tried to plot it using Prism but it is of course not as sophisticated as the example graph. RLS doubling time generated by Prism
And also it doesn't support sorting/synchronizing the data. Would love to learn how to achieve it in R or Python or any open source tool!

Not sure if this captures everything you want, but this looks straightforward to do in ggplot2. Here I make a custom repeating scale based on this answer.
# load the tidyverse meta-package, including ggplot2 & dplyr (for `n_distinct`)
library(tidyverse)

# load the sample data
df <- tibble::tibble(
  Cell = rep(1:3, c(9L, 9L, 8L)),
  Generation = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
                 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L),
  Doubling_time = c(40L, 70L, 80L, 100L, 100L, 80L, 90L, 70L, 190L, 50L, 90L, 100L, 
                    90L, 80L, 160L, 250L, 170L, 170L, 60L, 100L, 100L, 150L, 100L, 
                    130L, 120L, 450L),
)

# make a scale that copies a 5-color palette 1000x
color_mapping <- rep(viridis::viridis(5),1000)


# call ggplot2 on the df data,
#   specifying that x, y, and fill aesthetics should be mapped to these variables,
#   there should be a geom_col layer (oriented sideways)
#   and a custom fill scale that uses as many colors as there are Generations
ggplot(df, aes(Doubling_time, Cell, fill = factor(Generation))) +
  geom_col(orientation = "y") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_mapping[1:n_distinct(df$Generation)])


Scaling up to larger fake data, that looks like this. The main tweaking here would be to shrink the legend and only display every fifth value label...


Thank you so much!! This is super helpful. I'll try it out myself!!
